# F# Writing to file changes behavior on return type

Tags: f#, cntk

I have the following function that convert csv files to a specific txt schema (expected by CNTKTextFormat Reader):

```
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data;
open Deedle;

let convert (inFileName : string) = 
    let data = Frame.ReadCsv(inFileName)
    let outFileName = inFileName.Substring(0, (inFileName.Length - 4)) + ".txt"
    use outFile = new StreamWriter(outFileName, false)
    data.Rows.Observations
    |> Seq.map(fun kvp ->
        let row = kvp.Value |> Series.observations |> Seq.map(fun (k,v) -> v) |> Seq.toList
        match row with
        | label::data ->
            let body = data |> List.map string |> String.concat " "
            outFile.WriteLine(sprintf "|labels %A |features %s" label body)
            printf "%A" label
        | _ ->
            failwith "Bad data."
    )
    |> ignore
```

Strangely, the output file is empty after running in the F# interactive panel and that `printf` yields no printing at all.

If I remove the `ignore` to make sure that there are actual rows being processed (evidenced by returning a seq of nulls), instead of an empty file I get:

`val it : seq<unit> = Error: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.`

Before, I was declaring the `StreamWriter` using `let` and disposing it manually, but I also generated empty files or just a few lines (say 5 out of thousands).

What is happening here? Also, how to fix the file writing?

Comment: `Seq.map` is lazy. What you want is `Seq.iter`, which takes a side-effecting function (one that returns `unit`) and, NON-lazily, applies it to each item in the seq.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Seq.map` returns a lazy sequence which is not evaluated until it is iterated over. You are not currently iterating over it within `convert` so no rows are processed. If you return a `Seq<unit>` and iterate over it outside `convert`, `outFile` will already be closed which is why you see the exception.

You should use `Seq.iter` instead:

```
data.Rows.Observations
    |> Seq.iter (fun kvp -> ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the solutions already mentioned, you could also avoid the `StreamWriter` altogether, and use one of the standard .Net functions, `File.WriteAllLines`. You would prepare a sequence of converted lines, and then write that to the file:

```
let convert (inFileName : string) = 
    let lines = 
        Frame.ReadCsv(inFileName).Rows.Observations
        |> Seq.map(fun kvp ->
            let row = kvp.Value |> Series.observations |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList
            match row with
            | label::data ->
                let body = data |> List.map string |> String.concat " "
                printf "%A" label
                sprintf "|labels %A |features %s" label body
            | _ ->
                failwith "Bad data."
        )
    let outFileName = inFileName.Substring(0, (inFileName.Length - 4)) + ".txt"
    File.WriteAllLines(outFileName, lines)
```

**Update** based on the discussion in the comments: Here's a solution that avoids Deedle altogether. I'm making some assumptions about your input file format here, based on another question you posted today: Label is in column 1, features follow.

```
let lines = 
    File.ReadLines inFileName
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> 
        match Seq.toList(line.Split ',') with
        | label::data ->
            let body = data |> List.map string |> String.concat " "
            printf "%A" label
            sprintf "|labels %A |features %s" label body
        | _ ->
            failwith "Bad data."
    )
```

Comment: The cool thing is: you don't have to worry about the file size, sequences are lazy (well, at least not if ReadCsv is doing all the right things, which I suppose it does)

Comment: Oh my, haven't I learned anything. Is there a way to do such lazy loading in the input file lines too?

Comment: `File.ReadLines` is your friend

Answer (score 2):

As Lee already mentioned, `Seq.map` is lazy. And that's also why you were getting "Cannot write to a closed TextWriter": the `use` keyword disposes of its IDisposable when it goes out of scope. In this case, that's at the end of your function. Since `Seq.map` is lazy, your function was returning an *unevaluated* sequence object, which had closed over the `StreamWriter` in your `use` statement -- but by the time you evaluated that sequence (in whatever part of your code checked for the `Seq` of nulls, or in the F# Interactive window), the `StreamWriter` had already been disposed by going out of scope.

Change `Seq.map` to `Seq.iter` and both of your problems will be solved.